# SQL replace values in a table from another table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have two tables and I would like to replace a part of values from table1's column with values from table2's column.

To better explain:
[image]
I would like to put values in column "name" from table2 to column "name" in table1 on rows with id 3-9.

I'm working in Mysql workbench and MariaDB.

Comment: How is the relation between an `id` in `table1`to a row in `table2` defined? Is there a corresponding foreign key in `table2`?

Comment: So how to you know which `name` of `table2` is the one value for a `name` in `table1`?

Comment: `table2` has column pid that is a corresponding foreign key `id` from `table1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight forward approach is using a subquery in the `SET` clause.

```
UPDATE table1
       SET name = (SELECT t2.name
                          FROM table2 t2
                          WHERE t2.pid = table1.id)
       WHERE id >= 3
             AND id <= 9;
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking for a between operation. He said that just to clarify that it's an "inner" join operation.

Answer (score 2):

@stickybit's answer may work just fine, but I thought I would give an alternative using a [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) because it is more efficient than a subquery and [BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) because it makes the syntax a little simpler:

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.pid
SET table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table1.id BETWEEN 3 AND 9;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update table1 t1 
set t1.name=t2.name from table1 t1 ,table2 t2 
where t1.id=t2.id and id between 2 and 10
```

Comment: Syntax error: 'from' (from) is not a valid input at this position.